# Segfault only when running a C program without debugging

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've been working on a c program called `ft_split_whitespaces`.

What the program is supposed to do, is to find words and put them into a string array.

I have to do this for a project and I can't use any function except `malloc()` and `sizeof()`. I'm only using `printf()` and other stuff for debugging purposes.

So, I ran into a problem that when I would debug the program it would work fine and if I would run it I would get segfault.

I researched this topic and it turned out to be a heisenbug. I tried several ways to find the bug by turning off the debugger optimization but the result is always that if I go over the program step by step it works and otherwise, it won't.

Another weird thing I ran into that the program would work perfectly on my computer but when running on a different computer it would ones again segfault.

So here is my program and any help would be great.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define W1(c)   (c == ' ' ||  c == '\n' || c == '\t')
#define W2(c)   (c == '\v' || c == '\f' || c == '\r')

int     ft_wordcount(char *str)
{
    int i;
    int ws;

    ws = 1;
    i = 0;
    while (*str)
    {
        if (W1(*str) || W2(*str))
            ws = 1;
        else
        {
            if (ws)
                i++;
            ws = 0;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return (i);
}

int     ft_wordlen(char *str)
{
    int ln;

    ln = 0;
    while (!(W1(*str)) && !(W2(*str)) && *str != '\0')
    {
        ln++;
        str++;
    }
    return (ln);
}

char    **ft_assign(char *str)
{
    int     i;
    char    **res;
    int wordcount;
    int ln;

    i = 0;
    wordcount = ft_wordcount(str);
    res = (char **)malloc(wordcount * sizeof(char));
    while (i < wordcount)
    {
        if (!(W1(*str)) && !(W2(*str)))
        {
            ln = ft_wordlen(str);
            res[i] = malloc((ln + 1) * sizeof(char));
            res[i][ln] = '\0';
            str += ln;
            i++;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return (res);
}

char **ft_split_whitespaces(char *str)
{
    char    **res;
    int     i;
    int     wordcount;
    int     pos;

    wordcount = ft_wordcount(str);
    i = 0;
    res = ft_assign(str);
    while (i < wordcount)
    {
        if (!(W1(*str)) && !(W2(*str)))
        {
            pos = 0;
            while (!(W1(*str)) && !(W2(*str)) && *str != '\0')
                res[i][pos++] = *(str++);
            i++;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return (res);
}


int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int ln;
    i = 0;
    char test[] = "yes  no yuuh     WORD   adjdsfjlksdj   sdfjkdsfjkjsd     sfdkjsdlkjf  sfdds\tfsd";
    char **words;
    words = ft_split_whitespaces(test);
    ln = ft_wordcount(test);
    while (i < ln)
    {
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never need `* sizeof(char)`, that's always 1. Consider checking `*str != '\0'` before checking for whitespace. Look carefully at `res = (char **)malloc(wordcount * sizeof(char));` Are you allocating characters or pointers to characters? They are not the same size.

Comment: can we update the title to be more specific, as we get more info on the problem and solution? TIA.

Comment: As @Retired said, you are allocating a char instead of char*

Comment: @RetiredNinja Wow that really fixed it! Thanks so much, looking at this now is pretty embarrassing. I have two followup questions tho, why did it work with a debugger and is there a system where sizeof(char) != 1?

Comment: You accessed illegal memory locations by not allocating enough memory there. That invokes Undefined Behavior which means that anything could happen. In your case, it unfortunately happened to "work". `sizeof(char)` is mandated to be 1 by the C standard. So you can safely omit it, although its perfectly fine if you keep it there for brevity. I don't think there are systems where `sizeof(char) != 1`. If there were, then that implementation is not standard conforming.

Comment: Note that `sizeof` is an operator like `+` is an operator; it is not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- The argument in macros `W1` and `W2` is not properly parenthesized in the expansion. You should at least write this:

  ```
  #define W1(c)   ((c) == ' '  || (c) == '\n' || (c) == '\t')
  #define W2(c)   ((c) == '\v' || (c) == '\f' || (c) == '\r')
  ```

  but `c` would still be multiply evaluated, so side effects will occur multiple times. Don't use macros for this, use inline functions:

  ```
  static inline int W1(int c) { return (c == ' '  ||  c == '\n' || c == '\t'); }
  static inline int W2(int c) { return (c == '\v' || c == '\f' || c == '\r'); }
  ```
- The allocation sizes are incorrect in `ft_assign`: `res = (char **)malloc(wordcount * sizeof(char));` should be written:

  ```
  res = malloc(wordcount * sizeof(char *));
  ```

  or better:

  ```
  res = malloc(wordcount * sizeof(*res));
  ```
- You forget to copy the string into the allocated block: `res[i][ln] = '\0';` should be preceded by:

  ```
  memcpy(res[i], str, ln);
  ```

  Or if `strndup` is available on your system, simply replaced with

  ```
  res[i] = strndup(str, ln);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of your code is the `res` allocation, in `ft_assign`:

```
res = (char **)malloc(wordcount * sizeof(char));
```

Should be:

```
res = (char **)malloc(wordcount * sizeof(char*));
```

Or better:

```
res = malloc(wordcount * sizeof *res);
```

Indeed, `sizeof(char)` is one, `sizeof(char*)` is 4 (on 32bits cpu) or 8 (on 64bits), So by missing this simple `*`, you allocate too few memory.

---

See also: [why you should not cast malloc result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1212012)